# My iPhone 6 has white streaks lines and blue spots, can I fix it myself?

Tags: iphone

My phone got dropped in the snow and now has white streaking lines on the screen and blue patches but no lines. Can this be fixed? Is it permanent or can I easily fix it myself? It's an iPhone 6 and I am on a plan where I can't replace it for a while.

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. iOS devices that come with adhesive seals need some special tools and training to repair.

Most people can work odd jobs, cook meals at home, do other things to get paid for less time and money than taking the device to a repair shop to have someone do the work that is:

- already trained
- already purchased all the tools
- already knows where to get parts (and probably gets them in bulk for cheaper than we can)

That being said, don't let anyone say you shouldn't roll up your sleeves and try to learn / fix / break something. We all start somewhere and it's only money if you break your phone completely. Who is to say the experience you gain now isn't worth using a $45 flip phone for how ever many months it takes for you to save for a new iPhone? (*A: not me.*)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you'll need:

- replacement front panel assembly
- pentalobe screwdriver,
- 2-3mm philips screwdrivers
- suction cup/pad
- thin plastic prying tools
- **patience**

The parts used in the device are *tiny* and very easy to break or lose. Consider that apple charges around $100 for a screen replacement, and you're guaranteed to have a working phone after it's said and done. The same can't be said if you pick up a replacement screen and then accidentally damage the phone trying to get it apart.

[Here's a look at the disassembly instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+6+Front+Panel+Assembly+Replacement/29339) where you can decide if you want to go through with it or not.